# JS How to check if a class variable changed?

Tags: javascript, meteor, dom-events, meteor-blaze

I have a variable in a class that can change at any time? Is there a way that js can reactively check if it changed and if it did perform a function? I don't have control of the object, I can view it and modify it, but my code is not the only code that can do that.

Comment: You can manage the way this variable changes, like for example make any changes to this variable only through a certain function, in which you change the value, and do any other checks or changes you like in it.

Comment: I don't manage the variable, I can just view it.

Comment: Well, one *costly* solution, is to run an interval every short perion of time, which checks on the value of this variable and act upon change. But don’t do this unless the change to the variable is frequent.

Comment: @user10011538 I provided you a Meteor specific answer below. Did it help you to solve your issue? If not please provide more detail so we can work this out.

Answer (score 2):

If you are the owner of this object you can use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object on it to be used instead of original object. And this case you will have the total control on every single operation is produced with your object

Comment: Sorry I did not mention this, I don't have absolute control of the object, I can view it and modify it, but my code is not the only code that can do that.

Answer (score 0):

In Meteor (you have tagged it) you have the `Tracker` which autoruns a function if a reactive data source has been changed, no matter by whom or what.

Read: https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html

Now in Blaze (which you have also tagged) you have also a Template internal Tracker:

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function (){
  const instance = this

  instance.autorun(() => {
    // this behaves like Tracker.autorun
  })
})
```

How to to make a variable reactive?

If you access a reactive variable inside an autorun, you trigger the given function. A normal  Object is not reactive. In Meteor you can store data using

ReactiveVar: https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html

ReactiveDict: https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict

(Mini)mongo Cursor: https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#mongo_cursor

Accessing data from these data stores triggers computations of your trackers.

Reading these docs should make it clear to understand the reactive concept of Meteor and you should be able to write a reactive Template.